# Add a component script through script(C#) Unity5

Tags: c#, save, load, unity-game-engine

Good day everyone . I just need a little help from you fellow programmers. Can you help me with my problem. I want to add the script automatically from my **On Activate()** and **On Deactivate()**. How can i  obtain this. Please help me.

[image: See this photo]

Comment: I believe you can just use AddComponent<"script name">()

Comment: detector.OnActivate.AddListener();
 detector.OnDeactivate.AddListener();
I believe it is more like this . But i don't know how can i add the functions on the side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

detector.OnActivate.AddListener(); 
detector.OnDeactivate.AddListener();

By just doing this i already answered my own questions . Thanks anyway guys :)